# Python - While running a Selenium test, firefox window opens but remains blank

Tags: python, django, firefox, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing

I am writing tests in django (Python framework) using Selenium. When I run:

> python manage.py test myapp

then, a firefox window opens but remains blank. It stays for a few seconds and then it closes giving me a huge error message. Unfortunately, I cannot post the error message due to security issues.

The firefox version I'm using is: Mozilla Firefox 39
The selenium version is: 2.4.2

My test in tests.py file in myapp:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from django.test import TestCase

class MySampleTest(TestCase):  
    def setUp(self):  
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
        self.browser.implicitely_wait(3)  

    def tearDown(self):  
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_mytest(self):  
        self.browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

When I run my test, it gives me an error on this line:

> self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, according to what you are describing and taking into account that selenium 2.4.2 is very-very old, this is due to *compatibility issues between `selenium` and `Firefox`*. Upgrade `selenium` to the latest version (currently 2.46):

```
pip install --upgrade selenium
```